# Divisible numbers between two values, what do I return?

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate how many numbers between 20 ad 40 are divisible by 4.
My value is printing `There are 10 numbers divisible by 4` instead of `There are 6 numbers divisible by 4`

I am very new to programming, I am not sure if it is my maths that is wrong, my returning value or my for loop...why am I getting 10 instead of 6?

```
class Divisibility{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start = 20, stop = 40, divisor = 4;
        int count = countDivisible(start, stop, divisor);
        System.out.println("There are " + count + " numbers divisible by " + divisor);
    }

    public static int countDivisible(int start, int stop, int divisor) {
        int numbers = start;
        for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++)
            if ((i % divisor) == 0)
                numbers = i / divisor;
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to include the start and the end of your range in the count?

Comment: yes as 20 and 40 are divisible by 4, making it 6 numbers between 20&40 divisible by 4.

Comment: You should get used to encapsulating code with brackets {} even if there is only one line of code inside. It is more fail-proof for changes. Answers to your actual question are bellow.

Comment: The problem is that the countDivisible function is returning the value of division and not a count. Numbers should be incremented by 1 each time the modulus result is zero (0). What you are getting is the division of the stop number (40) by the divisor (4). That will always yield ten (10).

Answer (score 0):

You are returning result of dividing not the count.

```
    public static int countDivisible(int start, int stop, int divisor) {
        int numbers = 0;
        for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++){
            if ((i % divisor) == 0){
                numbers++;
            }
        }
        return numbers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result is `numbers = i / divisor` which ends up being 40 / 4.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
public static int countDivisible(int start, int stop, int divisor) {
    int numbers = 0;
    for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++)
        if ((i % divisor) == 0)
            numbers++
    return numbers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you *should* have the `count` starting at `0` and increment accordingly.

```
public static int countDivisible(int start, int stop, int divisor) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++)
            if ((i % divisor) == 0)
               count++;
        return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your countDivisible is wrong.. it must acumulate the times the condition meet the criteria

**i%divisor == 0**

```
public static int countDivisible(int start, int stop, int divisor) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++) {
        if ((i % divisor) == 0) {
            sum++;
            System.out.println(i + " is divisible by 4");
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I initialised `numbers` to 0, and replaced `numbers = i / divisor;` with `numbers++;`now it works, thank you.

```
public static int countDivisible(int start, int stop, int divisor) {
    int numbers = 0;
     for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++)
        if ((i % divisor) == 0)

        numbers++;

   return numbers;

}
```